# How to hardcode one item in cart in Opencart?

Tags: opencart

I have one item website. In order to make process faster, I want to navigate user directly to cart, when user clicks on "Buy" button.

I created function

```
function addToCartQuick() {
    // quantity = typeof (quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
    $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + 50 + '&quantity=' + 1,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                console.log('started to add');
                $('.js-btn-buy').html('Loading...');
            },
            success: function(json) {
                console.log('added');
                $('#cartlink')[0].click();
                $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();
                // window.location.href = 'index.php?route=checkout/simplecheckout';
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
    });
}
```

Which adds item to cart and clicks on hidden link to cart. As you see I also tried `window.location.href` but it is slower then navigating. Current solution is bit faster then `window.location.href` but still slow (comparing to just clicking on cart link)

Is there way to hardcode one default item in cart (of course give options to increase/decrease and remove item)?

Answer (score 1):

Added in catalog/controller/checkout/simplecheckout.php right below `function index() {`

`if (!$this->cart->hasProducts()) $this->cart->add(<your_product_id>);`

And then just changed Buy button to link directly to checkout/simplecheckout.